# Module Pattern Javascript - this binding

Tags: javascript

I have this following piece of code:

```
var myNamespace = (function() {

// A private counter variable
var myPrivateVar = 0;

// A private function which logs any arguments
var myPrivateMethod = function(foo) {
    console.log(foo);
    myPrivateMethod2();
};

var myPrivateMethod2 = function(foo) {
    console.log("Hi");
    myPrivateMethod3();
}

var myPrivateMethod3 = function() {
    console.log(3);
}

return {

    myPublicVar: "foo",

    myPublicFunction: function(bar) {

        myPrivateVar++;
        myPrivateMethod(bar);

    },

        myPublicFunction2: myPrivateMethod2
    };
})();
```

when the myPublicFunction is invoked, this context is window but when the myPublicFunction2 is invoked, this context is Object myNamespace. I expect it to be myNamespace in both the cases as call site is myNamespace. Why is it different?

Comment: Because you have an IIFE and the `this` inside a function is always `window` (or undefined in strict mode) unless its a method of an object in which `this` is the object (or if it's specifically bound). `myPublicFunction2` is a method of the returned object so `this` is the object, which is `myNamespace`.

Comment: but they're both "methods of objects" aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is not defined by how you define your object, but how you *invoke* its methods. So depending on *how* you make such calls, the same function may at one time have `this` set to a certain object, while another time it could be something else.

This behaviour can be overridden with `bind`, `call`, `apply` and similar methods.

The context will be set to `myNamespace` when you make your call like this:

```
myNamespace.myPublicFunction2()
```

... because of the prefix. But if that function would call yet another function, then the rules for determining the context will determine what `this` will be in that nested function call.

So after this code:

```
myNamespace.myPublicFunction()
```

... `this` will be set like you expect, but you lose that once you call:

```
myPrivateMethod(bar);
```

There is no prefix there, and so `window` is the context while that function runs (in non-strict mode).

#### Solution

You can circumvent that, by replacing that call with:

```
myPrivateMethod.call(this, bar);
```

Similarly, you'd want to do the same with the other calls you have to the private methods:

```
myPrivateMethod2.call(this);
// ...
myPrivateMethod3.call(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It helped.